# What number of minimum overs bowled makes an ODI cricket match goes in record books?

Tags: rules, cricket, statistics, interruption

For example, a scheduled ODI 50 overs match has been reduced to 10 overs or 15 overs due to rain, and a bowler takes a hat trick in those reduced overs. Will that record or any other made or achieved such a record will go on to the record books or not?

So my basic question remains, how many minimum overs are required for a one day match to be recorded as a full one day international match?

Answer (score 2):

From [Toss (cricket) - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toss_%28cricket%29)

> **If the match is abandoned at any time *after* the toss, it stands as a match played and enters official statistical records.** If a match is abandoned before the toss, it is not considered to have been played at all, and does not count for records.

So in cricket once the coin is tossed, the match is considered as a match played and enters official statistics. So if the match is abandoned after few overs say 10 or 15 it goes to official records. And there is no minimum overs requires to enter official statistics.

For a match to be considered as a completed match (unlike draw), each team must face 20 overs in One Day matches and 5 overs in Twenty20 matches before D/L method decide the result.
(Source: [Duckworth-Lewis method - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duckworth%E2%80%93Lewis_method#Application))

Answer (score 0):

The minimum that needs to be bowled for the game to constitute an official match is one ball. If the toss is completed but one ball is not bowled, the game is recorded as 'match abandoned without a ball bowled', but players still get credited with an appearance. Games called off *before* the toss are also recorded as 'abandoned without a ball bowled', but the players do *not* get awarded with an appearance.

The 20-over figure thrown around is the minimum number of overs required for a *result*, ie win, loss, tie or draw, using Duckworth-Lewis in one day internationals, however 'no-result' (games lasting under the required 20 overs) and 'abandoned' matches are both legitimate ways to end a match and therefore count in official records.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport. The answer is interesting when you are able to add any official references

Answer (score -1):

20 overs per side for an ODI match,  6 overs per side for a T20 match.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It would be nice to have a reference, but to drop a downvote without a comment?

Comment: @iandotkelly: Basically downvote means wrong/unresearched answer. Not every downvote requires a comment. #NotMyDownvote

Comment: @hims056 - particularly for a (potential) new user that is rather poor.

Comment: @iandotkelly - You are correct. At least downvote on new user's post requires a comment since they may not know how things work on Stack Exchange.